# Reference for the shloka "tvam ātmā puruṣa purāṇaḥ satya jyoti ananta ādya"

Tags: vedas, puranas, mantras, reference-request, shloka

I'm trying to find the reference for this shloka:

> tvam ātmā puruṣa purāṇaḥ satya jyoti ananta ādya
> त्वम आत्मा पुरुष पुराणः सत्य ज्योति अनंत आद्य

- त्वम (tvam): You
- आत्मा (atma): Self or soul
- पुरुष (purusha): Person or being
- पुराणः (puranaha): Ancient or eternal
- सत्य (satya): Truth
- ज्योति (jyoti): Light
- अनंत (ananta): Infinite
- आद्य (adya): Beginning or original

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is close enough to [Bhagavata Purana 10.14.23](https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/10/14/23/) that I think it's the verse you're looking for:

> ekas **tvam ātmā puruṣaḥ purāṇaḥ**
> **satyaḥ** svayaṁ-**jyotir ananta ādyaḥ**
> nityo ’kṣaro ’jasra-sukho nirañjanaḥ
> pūrṇādvayo mukta upādhito ’mṛtaḥ

Meaning (Swami Prabhupāda's):

> *You [Krishna] are the one Supreme Soul, the primeval Supreme Personality, the Absolute Truth — self-manifested, endless and beginningless. You are eternal and infallible, perfect and complete, without any rival and free from all material designations. Your happiness can never be obstructed, nor have You any connection with material contamination. Indeed, You are the indestructible nectar of immortality.*

---

Full Chapter: [Brahmā’s Prayers to Lord Kṛṣṇa](https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/10/14/#:%7E:text=You%20are%20the%20one,indestructible%20nectar%20of%20immortality.) for the context in the purport.

Comment: Where does this 'You' refer to 'Krishna' in the whole thing?

Comment: @User29449 - did you look at the link in the answer? There's a 'purport' section that offers the interpretation, and the other nearby lines in the chapter make clear that it's about Krishna,

Comment: How does 'purport' reached to this conclusion that it is Krishna speaking about it?

Comment: @User29449 - [Here](https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/10/14/) is the full chapter; please look at it. It begins _"This chapter describes the prayers Brahmā offered to Lord Kṛṣṇa, who is also known as Nanda-nandana."_ and is titled _"Brahmā’s Prayers to Lord Kṛṣṇa"_.

Comment: Perfect. You should add this link rather than that to your answer for the context to the readers.